# scrapy get data by post method but got 403

Tags: ajax, post, web-scraping, scrapy

I used both F12(Chrome) and postman to check the request and its detailed info on site

> http://www.zhihu.com/

(email:jianguo.bai@hirebigdata.cn, password:wsc111111), then go to

> http://www.zhihu.com/people/hynuza/columns/followed

I want to get all the columns the people Hynuza had followed which is 105 currently. When open the page, there is only 20 of them, then I need to scroll down to get more. Each time I scroll down the details of the request is like this:

```
Remote Address:60.28.215.70:80
Request URL:http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowedColumnsListV2
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:157
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_xsrf=f1460d2580fbf34ccd508eb4489f1097; q_c1=867d4a58013241b7b5f15b09bbe7dc79|1419217763000|1413335199000; c_c=2a45b1cc8f3311e4bc0e52540a3121f7; q_c0="MTE2NmYwYWFlNmRmY2NmM2Q4OWFkNmUwNjU4MDQ1OTN8WXdNUkVxRDVCMVJaODNpOQ==|1419906156|cb0859ab55258de9ea95332f5ac02717fcf224ea"; __utma=51854390.1575195116.1419486667.1419902703.1419905647.11; __utmb=51854390.7.10.1419905647; __utmc=51854390; __utmz=51854390.1419905647.11.9.utmcsr=zhihu.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/people/hynuza/columns/followed; __utmv=51854390.100--|2=registration_date=20141222=1^3=entry_date=20141015=1
Host:www.zhihu.com
Origin:http://www.zhihu.com
Referer:http://www.zhihu.com/people/hynuza/columns/followed
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
method:next
params:{"offset":20,"limit":20,"hash_id":"18c79c6cc76ce8db8518367b46353a54"}
_xsrf:f1460d2580fbf34ccd508eb4489f1097
```

Then I use postman to simulate the request like this:

[image]

As you can see, it got want I wanted, and it worked even I logout this site.

According to all of this, I write my spider like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import urllib
from scrapy.http import Request


class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "post"
    allowed_domains = ["zhihu.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.zhihu.com',
    )

    def __init__(self):
        super(PostSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'email': 'jianguo.bai@hirebigdata.cn', 'password': 'wsc111111'},
            callback=self.login,
        )

    def login(self, response):
        yield Request("http://www.zhihu.com/people/hynuza/columns/followed",
                      callback=self.parse_followed_columns)

    def parse_followed_columns(self, response):
        # here deal with the first 20 divs
        params = {"offset": "20", "limit": "20", "hash_id": "18c79c6cc76ce8db8518367b46353a54"}
        method = 'next'
        _xsrf = 'f1460d2580fbf34ccd508eb4489f1097'
        data = {
            'params': params,
            'method': method,
            '_xsrf': _xsrf,
        }
        r = Request(
            "http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowedColumnsListV2",
            method='POST',
            body=urllib.urlencode(data),
            headers={
                'Accept': '*/*',
                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Cookie': '_xsrf=f1460d2580fbf34ccd508eb4489f1097; '
                          'c_c=2a45b1cc8f3311e4bc0e52540a3121f7; '
                          '__utmt=1; '
                          '__utma=51854390.1575195116.1419486667.1419855627.1419902703.10; '
                          '__utmb=51854390.2.10.1419902703; '
                          '__utmc=51854390; '
                          '__utmz=51854390.1419855627.9.8.utmcsr=zhihu.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/;'
                          '__utmv=51854390.100--|2=registration_date=20141222=1^3=entry_date=20141015=1;',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                              'Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
                'host': 'www.zhihu.com',
                'Origin': 'http://www.zhihu.com',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            },
            callback=self.parse_more)
        r.headers['Cookie'] += response.request.headers['Cookie']
        print r.headers
        yield r
        print "after"

    def parse_more(self, response):
        # here is where I want to get the returned divs
        print response.url
        followers = response.xpath("//div[@class='zm-profile-card "
                                   "zm-profile-section-item zg-clear no-hovercard']")
        print len(followers)
```

Then I got 403 like this:

```
2014-12-30 10:34:18+0800 [post] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowedColumnsListV2> (referer: http://www.zhihu.com/people/hynuza/columns/followed)
2014-12-30 10:34:18+0800 [post] DEBUG: Ignoring response <403 http://www.zhihu.com/node/ProfileFollowedColumnsListV2>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

So it never enter the `parse_more`.

I've been working for two days and still got nothing, any help or advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you shouldn't mention your credential in here

Comment: @NaingLinAung It's ok, this account is just for test. By using this test account you guys can save some time.

Answer (score 0):

The login sequence is correct. However the `parsed_followed_columns()` method totally corrupts the session.

you cannot use hardcoded values for data['_xsrf'] and params['hash_id']

You should find a way to read this information directly from html content of previous page and inject the values dynamically.

Also, I suggest you remove the headers parameter in this request which can only cause trouble.

Comment: I tried what you said, and the `_xsrf` and `hash_id` is read from previous page, I put it there for simplicity.